# Programmatically deform planar texture to spherical (3d) texture

Tags: 3d, webgl, texture-mapping

I'm trying to deform a planar texture to a spherical texture *programmatically* so that I can use it on a sphere and not get the weird fish-eye effect. Basically I want to take a normal image and change it such that it maps without the fish-eye-ness on to a sphere.

I'm writing an webgl app, based on some videos I'm basically caching in a youtube bucket, so I can do this server side if necessary (currently using python), or if its fast enough in javascript on the client. Currently drawing spheres and mapping pre-deformed textures using a mercator projection technique, which looks fine, so I just need to figure out how to do the deforming.

Any suggestions very gratefully received! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the fragment shader, rather than deforming your image.  The fragment shader is doing texture lookups, and near the poles you'd want it to lookup values that are closer together in the image, while at the equator you'd want it to continue using the full width of the image for lookup.